# One line to loop over results of a function call with tuple (results, err)

Tags: loops, go, error-handling, slice

What's the best / standard way to iterate results from a function call where it returns the tuple `(result, err)`.

Example :

```
func getSlice() ([]string, error) {
  return []string{"a", "b", "c"}, nil
}

for _, letter := range getSlice() {} //how should it be done here?
```

Is that even a good thing to consider?

Answer (score 2):

If a function returns an error too, you should always check that first, and only proceed to use other results if the returned error allows so (most often if it's equal to `nil`).

So do it like this:

```
s, err := getSlice()
if err != nil {
    // Handle error and optionally return
    log.Printf("getSlice error: %v", err)
    return

}
for _, letter := range s {
    // Use letter
}
```

If you don't need to return in case of errors, and you only need to use the result once, you may also do it like this:

```
if s, err := getSlice(); err == nil {
    for _, letter := range s {
        // Use letter
    }
} else {
    log.Printf("getSlice error: %v", err)
}
```